# Not Throwing an error, but not logging to console to test

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Morning. I'm trying to calculate population density using for loop and if/else statements. When logging the results I get no errors but also get no log results for the variable density. Wonder if folks might be able to see what I'm missing in my functions. Thanks!

```
        var cityCoords = [[30.5833302, -114.2666702], [48.864716, 2.349014],[40.730610, -73.935242 ]] // city coords
        var cityPops = [8266000, 10958000, 19491339] // city populations
        var cityAreas = [3280, 41, 303]// city areas in sq. miles
        //    NOTE. You can use the arrays you built in Lab 3, just make sure you keep track of your variable names

        var button = document.getElementById("map-cities");

        button.addEventListener("click", function () {

            var units = prompt('Enter the units for calculating population density', 'Enter "miles" or "km"');

            var mapCities = function(){ // assign function to variable mapCities
            mapCities(units); // call mapCities function  units variable as an argument
        }
            // call a function named mapCities, and send the units variable as an argument

        }); // addEventListener callback function ends here

        // Define function
            function mapCities(units) {
                for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                    var cityName = cities[i] ;
                    var cityNumPeeps = cityPops[i];
                    var cityZone = cityAreas[i];

                    var density = calcPopDensity(CityNumPeeps, CityZone, units); // call calcPopDensity passing population, cityZone and units as arguments

                    console.log(density);

                }

            };



        function calcPopDensity(pop,area,unit){
            if (units == "miles"){
                cityZone/cityNumPeeps
                return

            } else if (units == "km"){
                cityZone * 1.60934 / cityNumPeeps
                return
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

There's... a few issues here. But, we all learn from our mistakes!

```
    var cityCoords = [[30.5833302, -114.2666702], [48.864716, 2.349014],[40.730610, -73.935242 ]]
    var cityPops = [8266000, 10958000, 19491339]
    var cityAreas = [3280, 41, 303]

    var button = document.getElementById("map-cities");

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {

        var units = prompt('Enter the units for calculating population density', 'Enter "miles" or "km"');

        mapCities(units); // <= You just want to call the function here, no need to do the function-wrapping you had!
    }

    });

    function mapCities(units) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) { // <= You don't actually have this array defined (cities)?
            var cityName = cities[i] ; 
            var cityNumPeeps = cityPops[i];
            var cityZone = cityAreas[i];

            var density = calcPopDensity(CityNumPeeps, CityZone, units); // <= match case - 'cityNumPeeps' vs 'CityNumPeeps' etc

            console.log(density);

        }

    };



    function calcPopDensity(pop,area,unit){
        if (units == "miles"){
            return cityZone/cityNumPeeps // <= move the return to this line - we want the result of the calculation back!

        } else if (units == "km"){
            return cityZone * 1.60934 / cityNumPeeps  // <= again, return statement
        }

    };
```

Comment: @ZacStanley no, you just have 'unit' in your `calcPopDensity` method, and 'units' in everything else  just rename the var

Comment: thank you very much @josh.trow. density is now logging to the console.